# How do I render whitespace when displaying ASCII art on a webpage?

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2

I am building a webpage that displays a player's pet monster (ASCII art) using a Flask server (app.py), a python file containing the art (gameData.py), a CSS file (style.css), and the HTML template (profile.html) that contains Jinja syntax. I am struggling to get the ASCII art to render to the webpage properly.

My problem:

- It seems as if some whitespace characters on each line are being ignored.

Some details:

- The ASCII art is stored as a list, with each line of the art at each index of the list.
- The list is passed into the HTML template via Jinja.
- The Jinja instructs the program to loop through the list, rendering each line.

Here is the ASCII image I am using to test:

```
[ 
"          ████████          ",
"        ██        ██        ",
"      ██▒▒▒▒        ██      ",
"    ██▒▒▒▒▒▒      ▒▒▒▒██    ",
"    ██▒▒▒▒▒▒      ▒▒▒▒██    ",
"  ██  ▒▒▒▒        ▒▒▒▒▒▒██  ",
"  ██                ▒▒▒▒██  ",
"██▒▒      ▒▒▒▒▒▒          ██",
"██      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒        ██",
"██      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒    ▒▒▒▒██",
"██▒▒▒▒  ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒  ▒▒▒▒▒▒██",
"  ██▒▒▒▒  ▒▒▒▒▒▒    ▒▒▒▒██  ",
"  ██▒▒▒▒            ▒▒▒▒██  ",
"    ██▒▒              ██    ",
"      ████        ████      ",
"          ████████          ",
"                            "
]
```

Here is the relevant HTML/Jinja block:

```
<!-- Draw pet here -->
    <div class="drawPet">
        {% for i in pet %}
            {{ i }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Here is the block of relevant CSS:

```
.drawPet {
    border: solid 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Here is how the webpage renders with the code as above:

[ASCII art on the webpage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXx6q.png)

Any advice in getting the egg to render like the python list is arranged?
Many thanks in advance.

I hope it's worth noting that I've tried different whitespace attribute values (pre, pre-wrap, etc) and have tried different HTML elements in the HTML block.

I also tried rendering the entire list without looping, but that just made a mess.

Comment: I'd bet that your lines aren't making it into your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the whitespace with a non-breaking space (&nbsp;)

```html
<!-- Draw pet here -->
    <div class="drawPet">
        {% for i in pet %}
            {{ i|replace(" ", "&nbsp;"|safe) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

**EDIT:** You also need to use a monospace font, and lower the line height for it to display with correct proportions

```css
.drawPet {
    border: solid 2px black;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: 'monospace';
    line-height: 1ch;
}
```

The final result looks like this:

[image: A pixel art egg]